Can obesity paradox among subjects with cardiovascular disease be explained by incorrectly controlling for a mediator?
Given the following causal diagram:
Obesity -> Cardiovascular disease -> Mortality
which follows from obesity being a causal factor of cardiovascular disease (CVD), isn't it reasonable to conclude that conditioning on subjects with CVD biases the treatment effect estimates because CVD is a mediator?
This may not explain the bias in entirety, but I'd think a significant portion of it.

This can result in bias, yes. If there are any unmeasured confounders between CVD and mortality, conditioning on CVD will open a back door thereby bias the effect estimate of obesity on mortality. This is called M bias

If we add CVD to the model, then the estimate for the effect of obesity is after controlling for CVD. That may or may not be what you want.  The whole subject of mediation models is about this.

Is obesity really the cause of cardiovascular disease or does it simply increase the risk of having cardiovascular disease?

@RogerV. Good question. I'm not a doctor, but the consensus seems to be yes, there is a physical mechanism that connects obesity and CVD.

In the given DAG:

Obesity -> Cardiovascular disease -> Mortality

...the effect of Obesity is completely mediated by Cardiovascular disease, which is probably not what you intended, as there are likely to be many other pathways from Obesity to Mortality that don't involve CVD.
But anyway, to the crux of the question, Yes, including a mediator in a regression can invoke the "reversal paradox" (for example Simpson's Paradox) - see Tu et al (2008). As the name suggests. not only can the reversal paradox lead to larger or smaller (biased) estimates, but it can actually change the sign of the estimate too.
References:
Tu, Y.K., Gunnell, D. and Gilthorpe, M.S., 2008. Simpson's Paradox, Lord's Paradox, and Suppression Effects are the same phenomenon–the reversal paradox. Emerging themes in epidemiology, 5(1), p.2.
